# Whats a simple Window Manager to use for web development?

Tags: gnu-screen, window-manager

I'm looking for a **really** simple window manager that will allow me to run a browser, a terminal and not much else.

I normally just use `chrome` along with `gnome-terminal` and a series of gnu `screen` sessions. The full gnome / unity / cinnamon desktop is overkill but I find the minimalist tiling window managers just conflict with the way I use screen.

Comment: use `metacity`.

Comment: that being said, I'm flagging your question, as it seems a little subjective. on Stack Exchange (welcome, btw!) we tend to prefer objective questions. I'm not quite sure if it will get closed or not, so we'll let the mods decide.

Answer (score 1):

One middle path for window managers is `[twm][1]`, which I believe comes with the X11 source distribution.  I've never found a distro that didn't have it, *BSD, Solaris included. `twm` is actually very configurable, so you can probably get to where you want to be very rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

use `metacity` as `window manager` , and use `tmux (Terminal MUltipleXer)` as session instead of `screen command`, `tmux command` has better than `screen`.use new version of `nautilus` + `gnome- shell`, You are programmer you can write extention with `gnome`.

Comment: I don't use screen either, but it's not deprecated. Please don't spread FUD.

Comment: I'm still using screen in 2015. Great when running rtorrent in the background, or when using unreliable ssh connections and running commands that take long to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend saving a lot of trouble and use Xubuntu. It has XFCE4 preconfigured. It's nice and snappy yet still very configurable. Gnome completely lost it after being butchered for years on end. No idea what got into the head of the Ubuntu boys with that awful window manager of theirs.
I used to use IceWM a lot, because it's nicely written in C++ and easy to get into the code and hack new features into it.
Now, it's mostly just XFCE4 because it does not get in the way.
KDE is nice too, but I hate those processes floating around, and it seems overly complex.